# .NET MVC display ViewData()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Right so. I created a new project in Visual Studio of type Internet Application.

In the HomeController.vb file I have:

```
Function Index() as ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "Page Title"
    Return View()
End Function
```

and in the view 'Index.aspx' I need that view data to be displayed between the ' < h1 > ' tags that I have.

I have looked around and found people saying to type:

```
 <%= ViewData["Message"] %>
or
 <% @ViewData["Message"] %>
```

but none of these are working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be using the wrong bracket? Should it not be?

`<%= ViewData("Message") %>`

EDIT: here is a VB.Net tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-vb

See heading `Using View Data to Pass Data to a View`

Comment: Thank you very much. All the examples were suggesting using the [] brackets so I had not even considered it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Just like you did in the Controller's Action, you should be using

```
<%= ViewData("Message") %>   <---- VB
```

Currently you are using the C# syntax

```
<%= ViewData["Message"] %>   <---- C#
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<%=Html.Encode(ViewData("message"))%>
```

The Html.Encode() HTML Helper encodes special characters such as < and > into characters that are safe to display in a web page. Whenever you render content that a user submits to a website, you should encode the content to prevent JavaScript injection attacks.